# SD of difference between means implies r > 1?

Tags: correlation, clinical-trials

I'm reading a paper, where they measure the pressure of patients before and after a treatment. Here are the quoted values for pre, post, and difference:

```
Pre   (n=43): 40.5 +- 7.6 (SD)
Post  (n=43): 17.8 +- 3.4 (SD)
Delta (n=43): 22.7 +- 3.2 (SD)
```

I want to estimate the implied correlation, within patients, between pre and post, using:

$$\hat{r} = \frac{\sigma_{pre}^2 + \sigma_{post}^2 - \sigma_{delta}^2}{2 \sigma_{pre} \sigma_{post}}$$

Which I derived from the well known formula for the SD of the difference in means of correlated normal variables.

However, the implied correlation between the pre and post measurements is greater than one! I wrote down the formula for the SDs and the means and I can't figure out a way to make these numbers work -- am I missing something? I did some simulations of some weird distributions and could not figure out a way to make the SD of the difference between variables be smaller than:

$$\sigma_{delta} \ge \sqrt{\sigma_{pre}^2 + \sigma_{post}^2 - 2\sigma_{pre}\sigma_{post}}$$

Which in this case, implies $\sigma_{delta} > 4.2$, which is not the case. I'm starting to think the numbers in the pape are bonk. I don't have access to the original data to test it out.

Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you are not missing something. Given these SDs, the correlation would be 1.14, which is not possible. There is a mistake in these numbers.

Comment: What would you if this study was one studies considered for meta-analysis? Would you reject it outright on the basis of fuzzy math? Would you correct for the inaccurate measurement?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to correct the numbers here. There is no obvious clue which of the SDS is off. Can you contact the researchers?

Comment: Pape was written 15 years ago, so doubt they have access to raw data. The range information however is also consistent with the SD of the delta being off, so that's a clue - like, the range is way too large for the SD, so that's a clue